# Solidity events and its's necessity

Tags: solidity, events

I don't understand solidity events at all. 
For example:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc5a79064168c0aa3706c33d70b94a09103e9656b#events
Some events show its names, others show methods without names and others show only data. Althought, I created similar events. Why it happens? Is it a problem if some events don't show it methods and names or it's normal in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, each event contains up to 5 "topics", plus arbitrary binary payload.  By convention, first topic is an address of a smart contract that logged the event.  Second topic is a keccak256 hash of event's signature, i.e. string looking like `OwnershipTransferred(address,address)`.  Three other topics are for `indexed` parameters of the event, and binary payload is for non-indexed parameters.  Event topics by themselves do not contain event name or any other human-readable information in open form.  Though, in case etherscan has source code of a smart contract, it can calculate keccak256 hashes of signatures of declared events, and thus decrypt the second topics.  What you think are methods, actually are events with parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't understand how etherscan decrypt events and I got the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The source code is not verified.

Look at other smart contracts that have verified source code. Then look at their events.

Example here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x54a298ee9fccbf0ad8e55bc641d3086b81a48c41#events

Comment: Honestly, I'm newbie and I don't see any difference with my code. I define the event in the contract and then emit it in the function. Does there any other important steps for using? [USDC](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#code), for example, doesn't show names of events. And how is it important to write down events correctly?